# vb.net Fill array with dataset

Tags: arrays, vb.net, vba, dataset

I'm trying to fill a class array with a DataSet that I retrieved from a table

If I populate a textbox directly from the DataSet it works perfectly, but population of the array gives me this exception, If `arry(i).ArrID` is an Integer

```
system.NullReferenceException
```

The line is this:

```
arry(i).ArrID = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0)
```

If `arry(i).ArrID` is a string, the Exception reads

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I'm new to VB and would appreciate some help, thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you initialized your array variable `arry` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA, the `Tables` object has a starting index of `1`, so if you're using an index of `0`, you're referencing a table that doesn't exist, hence the Null Reference.  You should also change the Item(0) reference, and ensure `i` is never set to `0`.  [[Source]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241522%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the response,
I hardcoded the 1's in as per your advice.

i=0
arry(i).ArrID = ds.Tables(1).Rows(1).Item(1)

with the same exception.

When I load into a textbox, using this code, it works perfectly.
i=0
SerReturn.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0)


But just in the middle of this post, I realized that the problem must be with my array, Ill post the answer when it gets figured out.